# How to add block and template to any page without using layout xml

Tags: blocks, template

Please help me and give me some example this question on title.
And How does method `toHtml()` work?

What is method `setPart()` used to do?

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: please mention magento version?

Comment: Please describe what you try. What happens? What did you expect?

Comment: I am new magento and i try research Module SplitShiping,
The module allow create vendors and assign to product.
It show info vendor when checkout cart, one page review but i cant find any its layout  and i cant understand why it can show out.

Answer (score 1):

This module rewrite some block : cart,review onpage...
And this is code in cart rewrited:

```
public function getItems()
{
    if (!Mage::helper('udsplit')->isActive()) {
        return parent::getItems();
    }
    $q = $this->getQuote();
    $a = $q->getShippingAddress();
    $methods = array();
    $details = $a->getUdropshipShippingDetails();
    if ($details) {
        $details = Zend_Json::decode($details);
        $methods = isset($details['methods']) ? $details['methods'] : array();
    }

    $quoteItems = $q->getAllVisibleItems();

    Mage::helper('udropship/protected')->prepareQuoteItems($a->getAllItems());

    $vendorItems = array();
    foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
        $vendorItems[$item->getUdropshipVendor()][] = $item;
    }

    $udsErr = null;
    $rates = array();
    $qRates = $a->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
    foreach ($qRates as $cCode=>$cRates) {
        foreach ($cRates as $rate) {
            $vId = $rate->getUdropshipVendor();
            if ($rate->getCode()=='udsplit_error') {
                $udsErr = $rate;
            }
            if (!$vId) {
                continue;
            }
            $rates[$vId][$cCode][] = $rate;
        }
    }

    $items = array();
    $dummyProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    foreach ($vendorItems as $vId=>$vItems) {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('carriers/udsplit/hide_vendor_name')) {
            $items[] = Mage::getModel('udsplit/cart_vendor')
                ->setPart('header')
                ->setQuote1($q)
                ->setData('product', $dummyProduct)
                ->setVendor(Mage::helper('udropship')->getVendor($vId));
        }
        foreach ($vItems as $item) {
            $items[] = $item;
        }

        $errorsOnly = false;
        if (!empty($rates[$vId])) {
            $errorsOnly = true;
            foreach ($rates[$vId] as $cCode=>$rs) {
                foreach ($rs as $r) {
                    if (!$r->getErrorMessage()) {
                        $errorsOnly = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } elseif ($udsErr) {
            $errorsOnly = true;
        }

        $items[] = Mage::getModel('udsplit/cart_vendor')
            ->setPart('footer')
            ->setData('product', $dummyProduct)
            ->setVendor(Mage::helper('udropship')->getVendor($vId))
            ->setEstimateRates(isset($rates[$vId]) ? $rates[$vId] : array())
            ->setErrorsOnly($errorsOnly)
            ->setShippingMethod(isset($methods[$vId]) ? $methods[$vId] : null)
            ->setItems($vItems)
            ->setQuote1($q);
    }
    return $items;
}

public function getItemHtml(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
{
    if ($item instanceof Unirgy_DropshipSplit_Model_Cart_Vendor) {
        $blockName = "vendor_{$item->getVendor()->getId()}_{$item->getPart()}";
       var_dump($blockName);
        return $this->getLayout()->createBlock('udsplit/cart_vendor', $blockName)
            ->addData($item->getData())
            ->setQuote($item->getQuote1())
            ->toHtml();
    }

    $renderer = $this->getItemRenderer($item->getProductType())->setItem($item);
    return $renderer->toHtml();
}
```

}

Comment: You need to check setPart() method in the module you will get idea how that module modifying layout